# CSS is not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, html, css, firefox, cross-browser

In my PHP page, I have applied CSS to a `<div>`. The CSS is working fine in Chrome but when I run my code in Firefox, then it is not applied.

```css
.due-money {
  background-color: #09C;
  color: white;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="due-money">
  <?=$al_data7['data'][$j]['money']?>
</div>
```

### Firefox

[image: Firefox screenshot]

### Chrome

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Comment: Looks fine. Define *"doesn't (get) applied"*. Also, what kind of string is in `$al_data7['data'][$j]['money']`? Consider using `htmlspecialchars()` to encode any accidental / unwanted HTML

Comment: Here is your fiddle. It looks working good. http://jsfiddle.net/RAtE3/

Comment: its working good for me

Comment: when i run it into mozila, then  then background color and text color is not changing. it's background color should be blue, and color should be white.

Comment: Its working good man!

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers use different CSS cores and interpret differently (To be unique, which just screws with standards) so you have to account for all browsers like so

```
.due-money
{
    background-color:#09C;
    color:white;
    width:20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:1px 2px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

More information for all browsers can be [found here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers)

Comment: ... Only if you count on updated browsers, which over 50% aren't. Including 25% still on XP and IE7... For example, my Android 2.3 relies on webkit.

Comment: @AmitKumar I don't see any difference in your screenshots but the width issue for user info. Can you take other specifically showing the rounded corner issue as well as your full CSS?

Comment: sir , there is differance in screenshot, in right side ,in chrome the background color is blue , but in mozila, there is no background

Comment: @AmitKumar That is not what your question is about, sir, and it seems your CSS is not triggered at all. Like I said, post the entire CSS page, it seems something is preventing it from executing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most probably not coming from this block of code.
Try debugging the surrounding elements. If you are using float to put the elements on the same line, you should make sure that you also have a clearing element when the line breaks.

If you check the rounded bordered element as stand alone, it is working on Firefox as well, at least on the version I am working on (I am using version 28.0 on Ubuntu). Knowing what version of Firefox you are using and under what operating system, could also help others help you.

If you are not using a clearing element, this is what I use.

The HTML:

```
<div class="clear"> </div>
```

The css:

```
.clear { clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 0; line-height: 0; font-size: 0; }
```

If this still did not solve your problem, keep on debugging the surrounding elements style as there might also be an inheritance case causing you this issue.

*Perhaps you could update your post with the code for the Friend Report section.